# Mass as generator of two distinct sets of phenomena

Tags: special-relativity, mass, inertial-frames, chirality, helicity

We know that mass, which is a continous parameter, generates two classes of different phenomena: the ones where $m=0$ and the ones with $m \neq 0$.

When a particle has $m=0$ we have phenomena which belong only to this class of particles, such as:

- no rest frame for the particle
- chirality same as helicity

When a particle has $m \neq 0$ we have phenomena which belong only to this class, and the separation holds even with masses arbitrarily small but different from zero, such as:

- a rest frame
- chirality different from helicity

So why, if mass is a continous parameter (you can go arbitrarily close to zero without being zero), do you have a totally different set of phenomena for exactly and only $m=0$?

How do these two "discrete" sets of phenomena emerge from the change of a continuous parameter?

My first thought goes to the difference between lightlike and timelike quantities, but to me it seems only a redefinition of the question in different words (geometric ones).

Comment: To clarify: you have 2 distinct not overlapping sets of phenomena that are separated by a quantity which you can take arbitrarily close to zero without those 2 sets ever coming close one another. To me that's a bit weird

Comment: FYI: You can edit your original question at any time. If you feel that you left something out, your ability to amend it is not limited to adding these comments.

Comment: I know, i didn't want to make i a text wall by adding a (maybe superfluous) note

Comment: What you are describing is called a "singular limit": a limit in which the change of a system parameter results in qualitative changes. (For example when in the limit parameter$\rightarrow 0$ you loose the highest-order term in a differential equation.) You can find discussions of such singular limits in the context of emergent phenomena and in quite a wide variety of physical applications.

Comment: (I know that this probably goes beyond what is asked here, but indeed considering a "singular limit" can lead to quite different mathematical structures. In particular, in group-theoretical language this may be described in terms of [group contractions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_contraction) (İnönü–Wigner contractions). Thus, when we consider the Poincaré group, the stability group is $\rm SO(3)$ in the massive case ($m>0$), but it becomes a different group, $\rm ISO(2)$, in the limit $m\to0$.)

Comment: @printf thank you, this also is very interesting. I was thinking of this as a phenomenon similar to phase transitions and hence spontaneous symmetry breaking. I will check İnönü-Wigner contractions!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Zero is special: it is the only real number without a multiplicative inverse.  The real numbers are therefore naturally divided into two discrete sets: those with a multiplicative inverse, and those without.  It should therefore not be too surprising that we see applications such as this one where that division makes itself apparent.

You said yourself that there's a difference between lightlike and timelike paths: it's impossible to transform a lightlike path to a timelike one, and therefore it's impossible to find a rest frame for a lightlike particle.  The Lorentz factor, which tells us how the coordinates must contract in order to transform to the rest frame, is given by

$$
\gamma = \frac{E}{mc^2},
$$

where $E$ is the energy of the particle, $m$ is the mass, and $c$ is the speed of light.  When the mass is zero, we literally get a divide-by-zero error, thus showing that the unique property of zero being the only real number without a multiplicative inverse is directly related to why massless particles have no rest frame.

Comment: I never thought about this property for the real line, thank you!

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regularization_(physics) - in general.